# How to use constructors in order to print out Subject, color and pages for each book?

Tags: java, compiler-errors, cannot-find-symbol

How to use constructors in order to print out Subject, color and pages for each book?

I'm fairly new, please forgive me. Whenever I attempt to enter Book1.bookSubject it states that there is a cannot find symbol error.

```
public class Books_A  
{ 

public static void main(String args[]) 

{

bookData Book1 = new bookData("geometry", "blue", 756);

bookData Book2 = new bookData("algebra", "green", 805);

bookData Book3 = new bookData("algebra", "red", 884);



System.out.println("Title             Color            Pages");
System.out.println( + Book1.bookSubject );




}
}

class bookData
{

String Subject;

String Color;

int Pages;

bookData( String bookSubject, String bookColor, int bookPages)

{

bookSubject = Subject;

bookColor = Color;

bookPages = Pages;

}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to write:

```
System.out.println(Book1.Subject);
```

`bookSubject` is a local variable for that constructor, and as such, can be used only within it. But since you made `Subject` a global variable, you can access it from anywhere outside the class, through the object name.

Answer (score 0):

There are few mistakes in your code. Read comments after every line.

```
public class Books_A  
{ 

    public static void main(String args[]) 
    {

        BookData Book1 = new bookData("geometry", "blue", 756);
        BookData Book2 = new bookData("algebra", "green", 805);
        BookData Book3 = new bookData("algebra", "red", 884);

        System.out.println("Title             Color            Pages");
        System.out.println(  Book1 ); // prints book 1 info
        System.out.println(  Book2 ); // prints book 2 info
        System.out.println(  Book3 ); // prints book 3 info


     }
 }

class BookData // Class name start with captital
{

    String subject; // member names always start with lowercase
    String color;   // member names always start with lowercase
    int pages;      // member names always start with lowercase

    BookData( String bookSubject, String bookColor, int bookPages)
    {

        subject= bookSubject ; // in your code assignment was reverse
        color=bookColor ;  // in your code assignment was reverse
        pages=bookPages ;  // in your code assignment was reverse

     }

     //Override toString method on bookData class.

     @Override
     public String toString() {
        return this.subject+"\r"+this.color+"\r"+this.pages;
     }

  }
```